How to filter specific tags without including synonyms?
If I want to filter a specific tag that has a synonym, the behavior is that the synonym tag will also be filtered along with the initial tag.
On DIY, [electrical] (18k entries) is a synonym for [electrical-distribution] (87 entries).

In my specific case, I want to filter only [electrical-distribution], but instead, I get 18k results, which include all questions tagged [electrical].
Is it possible to list only those 87 questions explicitly tagged [electrical-distribution]?

The search logic for these sorts of searches was somewhat recently changed and was met with... Some mixed feedback. The biggest concern expressed in the comments is, in a situation where a synonym is created between [a] -> [b], searching for [a] searches instead for [a] or [b], but searching for [b] only searches for [b], not including [a], which doesn't seem to coincide with the intent of the synonym system.

All that aside, when synonyms are approved, a tag merge should probably take place (assuming the synonym makes sense), which will rewrite all questions tagged (using the above example) [a] to instead be tagged [b].

@Spevacus Merging the tags would result in the expected system behaviour.

I don't think so. This is likely answerable via a Stack Exchange Data Explorer query, or some other somewhat-hacky solution that I haven't dreamed up.

Would you be satisfied with getting this using SEDE: Is there a way (e.g. with SEDE) to find questions with an existing tag that's been synonymized (but not merged) into another tag?  Here is the linked SEDE query for the tag electrical-distribution.

@Martin That's exactly what I was looking for. You can either post it as an answer. Or we close this question as a dupe.

Perhaps it is reasonable to keep this question open - IMO it is not exact duplicate. (The other one asks specifically about SEDE, this question asks about any solution.) So I posted the SEDE query as an answer - we'll see whether somebody has some other reasonable suggestion.

If you're satisfied with a solution using SEDE, you can use the query from here: Is there a way (e.g. with SEDE) to find questions with an existing tag that's been synonymized (but not merged) into another tag? (Or some modification of that query.)
For example, here is what you get for the tag electrical-distribution.
Keep in mind that SEDE is only updated once a week - so the results might be a bit behind the current state on the site.
At the moment this query returns 87 questions. For example, this one: Is it acceptable to have two circuits with a shared hot but different neutrals? You can see that the question indeed has the tag electrical-distribution rather than the master tag electrical - which means that these two tags haven't been merged.

It was pointed out in comments that there were some (relatively) recent changes to the way tag synonyms are handled in search. We'll see whether somebody can suggest something useful directly using the site interface. (Or whether some more changed to this are still to come.)

"t was pointed out in comments that there were some (relatively) recent changes to the way tag synonyms are handled in search. We'll see whether somebody can suggest something useful directly using the site interface." the synonym and search logic is almost entirely useless for exploring synonymised tags. Only works without additional filters and even then only works if you pick a single synonym. You can't, for example find all questions that match two synonyms. "(Or whether some more changed to this are still to come.)" hopefully, otherwise SEDE really is the only option.
